# Elasticsearch sub-aggregation excluding key from parent

Tags: elasticsearch

I am currently doing an aggregation to get the top 20 terms in a given field and the top 5 co-occuring terms.

```
{
"aggs": {
    "descTerms" : {
        "terms" : {
            "field" : "Desc as Marketed",
            "exclude": "[a-z]{1}|and|the|with",
            "size" : 20
        },
        "aggs" : {
            "innerTerms" : {
                "terms" : {
                    "field" : "Desc as Marketed",
                    "size" : 5
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Which results in something like this:

```
 "key": "bluetooth",
           "doc_count": 11172,
           "innerTerms": {
              "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
              "sum_other_doc_count": 33700,
              "buckets": [
                 {
                    "key": "bluetooth",
                    "doc_count": 11172
                 },
                 {
                    "key": "with",
                    "doc_count": 3827
                 }
```

I would like to exclude the key in the sub aggregation as it always returns as the top result (obviously) I just can't seem to figure out how to do so.

aka I want the previous to look like this:

```
"key": "bluetooth",
               "doc_count": 11172,
               "innerTerms": {
                  "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
                  "sum_other_doc_count": 33700,
                  "buckets": [
                     {
                        "key": "with",
                        "doc_count": 3827
                     }
```